# Algorithm to bring evens to front of array: How to incorporate corner case elegantly?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, optimization

I actually have a few problems pertaining to my attempt at an implementation of the "Bring the evens to the front" or similar partition-type interview question. Here's the implementation:

http://codepad.org/eO0c6Sbj

```
#include <stdio.h>

void intSwap ( int * a, int * b )
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b; 
    *b = temp;
}

void evensToFront ( int * arr, int n )
{
    if (n < 2) return; // if size of array is 0 or 1
    int * end = arr + n - 1; // pointer to last element
    do
    {
       if (*arr % 2 == 1) // if first pointer is odd
       {
           if (*end % 2 == 0) // if second pointer is even
           {
               intSwap(arr,end); // swap first and second
           }
           else // second pointer is not even
           {
               // move second pointer towards first until even or hits first
               do --end;
               while ((arr != end) && (*arr % 2 == 1));
           }
       }   
       else
       {
           ++arr;
       }  
    } while (arr != end); // while first pointer not equal to second

}


int main ( )
{
    int arr [] = {0, 69, -13, 100, 2, 2, 5};
    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    evensToFront(arr,len);
    int * p1 = arr, * p2 = (arr + len);
    for (;p1!=p2;++p1) printf("%d ", *p1);
    return 0;
}
```

1. Why is the output `0 69 -13 100 2 2 5`? In other words, where is the flaw in my algorithm?
2. Why is the online compiler not letting me define variables within `for` loops? When I change the `for` loop to the more straightforward `for (int k = 0; k < len; ++k) printf("%d ", arr[k]);` I get the error

> 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode.

3. How do I get rid of the line `if (n < 2) return;` that I have for dealing with the corner case? Ideally, the corner case would be dealth with in the logic of the outermost `while` loop without adding any extra operations to the algorithm.

Comment: "Why is the online compiler not letting me define variables within for loops?" - because that construct didn't get into the C standard until C99, and the compiler isn't running in a mode that allows that construct.

Comment: As for the 3rd part, instead of a `do {...} while` outer loop, consider `while (arr < end) { ... }`

Comment: @Larry Page  You were deceived. It was not an interview. It was an exam.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least here there is a typo

```
while ((arr != end) && (*arr % 2 == 1));
                        ^^^^^^
```

I think you mean

```
while ((arr != end) && (*end % 2 == 1));
                        ^^^^^^
```

And if you want to exclude statement

```
if (n < 2) return; // if size of array is 0 or 1
```

then you should define `end` like

```
int * end = arr + n; // pointer to past the last element
```

and process the `end` correspondingly. For example

```
while ( arr != end )
{
   //...
```

Take into account that usually such functions return the partition point that is the pointer that separates the partitions.

And usually instead of

```
if (*arr % 2 == 1)
```

it is better to write

```
if ( *arr % 2 )
```

or

```
if ( *arr & 1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what Vlad mentioned, there is another subtle error:

```
if (*arr % 2 == 1)
```

You have negative numbers, and `-13 % 2 == -1`. To avoid this, use:

```
if (*arr % 2 != 0)
```

and

```
while ((arr != end) && (*end % 2 != 0));
```